# How to deploy the flask web heroku with nlkt rake

Tags: python, flask, heroku, deployment, dependencies

In my flask app I used nlkt rake()
The app run perfectly on local. Once I deploy to the heroku build is success but my app not working only the error on build log is I added below. Anyone please suggest another way to deploy or help me with this deployment

`from rake_nltk import Rake`

I referred
[Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-nltk)

Deployment error:
[Build log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHA8H.jpg)

nlkt.txt

```
popular
stopwords
wordnet
punkt
pros_cons
reuters
```

requirements.txt

```
certifi==2020.6.20
click==7.1.2
cycler==0.10.0
Flask==1.1.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
joblib==0.16.0
kiwisolver==1.2.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.3.2
nltk==3.5
numpy==1.19.2
pandas==1.1.2
Pillow==7.2.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.1
rake-nltk==1.0.4
regex==2020.7.14
scikit-learn==0.23.2
scipy==1.5.2
six==1.15.0
threadpoolctl==2.1.0
tqdm==4.49.0
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

note: this is my first question if you need more information or doubts about the question please comment

Comment: what type of app?